# Set the annotations directory for OCaml in emacs

Tags: emacs, ocaml

I'm part of a big project and, sadly, the `.annot` files are not located in the `.ml` files directory. So, naturally, when I do `C-c C-t` it answers

> No annotation file. Compile with option "-annot" or set 'caml-annot-dir'.

I checked, my `.annot` files are in a directory (let's say in `../build`) and I'd like to tell tuareg that when I'm working on this project it should look in this directory (by setting `caml-annot-dir` which I can't find) but I have no idea of how to set this variable and even more how to set if forever but only for this project (maybe with Local variables ?).

Comment: Annot finding is not by tuareg but by `ocaml-types.el`, bundled with OCaml compiler.

Comment: OK. But anyway, how can I set this directory? ;-)

Comment: Just out curiosity, are you aware of Merlin? As it will overload `C-c C-t` command that will work much better and mostly without any additional configuration burden.

Comment: I'm not really fond of Merlin, mostly because of the live evaluation adding all of these `!`. Maybe there's a magical (magical? You get it? :-P) configuration for it but till I hear about it I'll keep working with almost nothing. Actually, I previously answered advising Merlin. ;-)

Comment: same issue here, I thought things would work out-of-the-box, what are these annotation files?

Comment: @David天宇Wong That's an old question. These annot files were created by old versions of the compiler and you shouldn't have to use them today (with a modern version of OCaml). Do you mind telling me what your environment is for you to need annot files?

Comment: I'm using ocaml 4.14.0 with emacs 28.2 and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note first that directories in `caml-types-build-dirs` are searched in parent directories of your file.  In your case, you should do `(add-to-list 'caml-types-build-dirs "build")`.  If completing this list does not work, you can set the location on a file basis, using local variables: put at the end of your file

`(* Local Variables: *)
(* caml-annot-dir: "/path/to/directory/annot" *)
(* End: *)`

Comment: It is not tuareg which says `No annotation file. Compile with option "-annot"`.  It is `caml-types.el`.  Anyway, check https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables for more details.

Comment: Hahaha @camlspotter, don't lose patience! ;-)

Comment: @chris, maybe you should edit your answer since your first sentence repeats exactly what I said. I will try the local variable (why didn't I try before asking?!)

Comment: @Lhooq Followed your suggestion and added instruction in case your annot files are indeed in `../build`.